# Apache Sending "Content-Length : 0" , How to Fix?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, configuration

I am using Apache server and it is sending Content-Length = 0 value which is preventing file-downloads, see - http://www.youtubedroid.com/download2.php?v=_3XcMEKNws0&title=Akhila+%2CMumbai+reloaded%2CSuper+dancer+2&hq=0 , here are my .htaccess content :

```
SetEnv no-gzip dont-vary
```

Here are headers sent by the server :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2009 06:12:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.11
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Akhila ,Mumbai reloaded,Super dancer 2.mp3"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: public
X-Sendfile: ./tmp/64eb3b185e38af95c15405ffb0606e76.mp3
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=95
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Pls. tell how to fix this ?

Comment: Please phrase your question in the form of a question.

Comment: Michael - I hope it's better now :)

Comment: My guess is that this is a programming issue.  The download2.php script is responsible for setting the length and such.  I see you are using sendfile() or its like, which, so long as it can read the file, should "just work."

Comment: I would suspect your script is outputting nothing. Triple check your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

X-Sendfile header won't be sent by apache, so probably you haven't enabled xsendfile in that virtual host. When XSendFile is enabled, apache will be remove X-SendFile header and will sent the file.

Answer (score 0):

The [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4) says

> The Content-Length header field MUST
>   NOT be sent if these two lengths are
>   different (i.e., if a
>   Transfer-Encoding header field is
>   present). If a message is received
>   with both a
>        Transfer-Encoding header field and a Content-Length header field,
>        the latter MUST be ignored.

So it looks like your server is working correctly for this particular request. This implies the fix is to send the correct file length in the header and not send the Content-Transfer-Encoding header if you have that level of control over what the app is sending.